# How to run maven site along with normal install/package goals

Tags: java, maven, build-process, maven-release-plugin

We are trying to generate change log and some other reports using maven. We are using the **changelog** plugin and **site** plugin. But We generate the report using the :

`mvn clean package site` command. Is there any way that I can skip giving the **site goal** , and  make maven generate the report automatically when I do a mvn install/package?

My idea is to generate the report and copy it inside the war so that certain users can access it and see the changelog, after I do a normal maven build/package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh stupid me, I can do it with:

```
<executions><execution>...</execution><executions>
```

Thanks.